# Styling a list in sharepoint 2013 with JSLink returns [object HTMLDivElement] instead of content

Tags: 2013, javascript, item-styles

I have a news list in sharepoint that I'm trying to style with jslinks, but for some reason it returns the [object HTMLDivElement]. the footer appears correctly and is styled, but the column styling for 'notes', 'title' and 'expires' doesn't show. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
This is the code in the jslink

```
"use strict";
window.News = window.News || {};
window.News.LIST_NAME = "News";

(function () {
    // Ensure the core js class is loaded
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        // CSR-override for MDS enabled site
        RegisterModuleInit(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/SiteAssets/News/News.js", RegisterNewsCustomizations);
    }, 'sp.js');

    // Register the Customizations
    RegisterNewsCustomizations();
})();

// Register the JSLink List/View Customizations
function RegisterNewsCustomizations() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        Templates: {
            Header: headerTemplate,
            Item: itemTemplate,
            Footer: footerTemplate
        }, ListTemplateType: 104
    });
}


// The header
function headerTemplate(ctx) {
    if (ctx.ListTitle != window.News.LIST_NAME) { return RenderHeaderTemplate(ctx); }
    // set main container
    var container = " ";
    return container;
}

//the footer
function footerTemplate(ctx) {
    if (ctx.ListTitle != window.News.LIST_NAME) { return RenderFooterTemplate(ctx); }
    var footer = document.createElement("div");
    footer.setAttribute("class", "newsFooter");
    footer.innerHTML = "<a class=\"newsApp-more\" href=\"" + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/Lists/News/AllItems.aspx#\">More news >></a>";
    var div2 = document.getElementById("DeltaPlaceHolderMain");
    var parentDiv = div2.parentNode;
    // Insert the new element div1 after div2
    div2.parentNode.insertBefore(footer, div2.nextSibling);
    return footer;
}

function itemTemplate(ctx) {

    function modalOpen() {
        var options = { title: ctx.CurrentItem["Title"], html: "<p>" + ctx.CurrentItem["Note"] + "</div>" };
        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
    }
    if (ctx.ListTitle != window.News.LIST_NAME) { return RenderItemTemplate(ctx); }
    //set all variables
    var itemHtml = document.createElement("div");

    itemHtml.innerHTML = "<a class= \"newsApp-title\" href=\"javascript:modalOpen()\">" + ctx.CurrentItem["Title"] + "</a><div class=\"newsApp-date\">" + ctx.CurrentItem["Expires"] + "</div>"
    return itemHtml;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
var itemHtml = document.createElement("div");

itemHtml.innerHTML = "<a class= \"newsApp-title\" href=\"javascript:modalOpen()\">" + ctx.CurrentItem["Title"] + "</a><div class=\"newsApp-date\">" + ctx.CurrentItem["Expires"] + "</div>"
return itemHtml;
```

Creates a DOM node and returns a DOM node, so is converted to a string representation `[object HTMLDivElement]` when displayed in the Browser

**SharePoint CSR function must return a String (HTML):**

```
var itemHtml = "<div><a class= \"newsApp-title\" href=\"javascript:modalOpen()\">" + ctx.CurrentItem["Title"] + "</a><div class=\"newsApp-date\">" + ctx.CurrentItem["Expires"] + "</div></div>"
return itemHtml;
```

If you want to develop more fancy CSR stuff; the [iCSR library](http://iCSR.github.io) makes CSR development a bit easier

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and the link! I've edited my code and my title appears with styling but I'm getting an undefined instead of the expires date (though it is styled correctly) and error: invalid argument thrown back instead of the footer now [link to image of error] (http://imgur.com/ennpE58)

Comment: Then "Expires" is not defined in the CurrentItem. Trace ``ctx.CurrentItem.Expires`` in the console and see what it is.. Note that ctx is a global object and the console will only show the current state of Objects in the console... Not what ctx was in the function..You can find the correct Internal names in the ``ctx.ListSchema.Field`` array. BTW your modalOpen function is not defined in the global scope, so ``javascript:modalOpen`` won't work either.